# How do I output the name instead of the foreign key id in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I output the `formulation_name` instead of the `id` that it is currently outputting. I have looked for an answer for a while but couln't get the right solution.

In the table `object`, `formulation_fk` column is the foreign key of the `id` of the table `formulation`. This is my two tables.

[image: datatable]

I have come ths far with the following query to output the `Name` and `Formulation id`. But what should be the query to display the `formulation_name` instead of `id` in the table `object`?

```
<?php 
    require_once 'db_connect.php';
    
    $output = array('data' => array());
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM object";
    $query = $connect->query($sql);
    
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    
        $output['data'][] = array(
            $row['name'],
        );
}
```

[image: OutputTable]

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: google how to do an inner join

Comment: You need to learn how to do JOINs. They should be covered by any introductory SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with [`inner join`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwju8dmxqOPWAhUISY8KHYQiBTQQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fsql%2Fsql_join_inner.asp&usg=AOvVaw0R92wNG-BvHjI40mlknp16) the table .In your diagram, you mention the table is the object but the SQL query your mention with `output`.I was just write the code with `object` table from diagram

```
   "SELECT object.name,formulation.formulation_name as formulation FROM object INNER JOIN formulation ON object.formulation_fk = formulation.id"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a typo in my image. But your solution works perfectly. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM object INNER JOIN formulation ON object.formulation_fk = formulation.id";
```

BTW: Better structure should be:

```
Object: object_id, object_name, formulation_id
Formulation: formulation_id, formulation_name
```

You will avoid the ambiguity of names.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on the structure, but I'm sorry that the query returns an error.

Comment: @RajibBiswas that's because the answer is suggesting that you change your table names first (hence the word "structure"). IMHO it's just a matter of naming conventions, but what is suggested here is more common that your naming (i.e. putting the _id at the end so it matches the primary key field, rather then _fk_ at the end). But it's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: And when primary key and foreign keys have this same name you can use `LEFT JOIN table USING(key_name)`

Comment: Thank you very much @ADyson. You're right that it makes the columns more recognizable and more organized. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks again.